# Replace parameter values on one file (.properties) from values from another file (.json)

Tags: sed, json

I have a file which is `some.properties` file, which has parameters.

```
DATABASE_NAME=${DB_NAME}
DATABASE_HOST=${DB_HOST}
..
..
..
```

I have another file which is `demo.json` file and has values:

```
{
  "database_conf" : {
    "DB_NAME": "ABC",
    "DB_HOST": "HOST_ABC",
    "..": "..",
    "...": "..."
  }
}
```

How to write a shell script file to update the `some.properties` file with the values mentioned in the `demo.json` file.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the JSON document with `jq` to create a `sed` script, then run that script on your file:

```
$ jq -r '.database_conf | to_entries | .[] | "s,=\\${\(.key)},=\"\(.value)\","' demo.json | sed -f /dev/stdin some.properties
DATABASE_NAME="ABC"
DATABASE_HOST="HOST_ABC"
..
..
..
```

The `jq` expression will create a `sed` expression for each key-value pair in the `.database_conf` object.  The output of `jq` for the given data will be the following `sed` script:

```sed
s,=\${DB_NAME},="ABC",
s,=\${DB_HOST},="HOST_ABC",
s,=\${..},="..",
s,=\${...},="...",
```

This is then read by `sed -f` to perform the actual substitutions on the properties file.

This assumes that each and every variable in the properties file is written as `${variablename}` and that they are always immediately preceded by a `=` character.

To make the changes in-place, you may want to use `sed -i`, otherwise redirect the result to a new file.

If your data contains commas, change the commas in the output expression of `jq` to some other character that is not used in your data.

If you have additional top-level objects with configuration, then add these as a comma-delimited list at the start of the `jq` expression. For example:

```
jq -r '.application_conf, .database_conf | to_entries (..etc..)
```

Comment: This works fine if the json is simple. For the multi hierarchy json, it is not reading the values. For eg. `{
  "database_conf" : {
    "DB_NAME": "ABC",
    "DB_HOST": "HOST_ABC",
    "..": "..",
    "...": "..."
  }, "application_conf" : {
    "APP_DIR": "SOME_PATH",
    "HOST_URL": "http://abc.com/sed"
} }`. Also, if the json has a URL the `jq` fails to parse.

Comment: @coolTech I might look into this and update the answer in a little bit, but I originally wrote it _specifically_ for the JSON document that you showed. Also, do you have an example of an URL that fails to parse? Presumably if it contains an `&` or `;`, right? That should be easily fixed by inserting  quotes around the right hand side of the assignments.

Comment: @coolTech See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I appreciate your help. Now it is parsing multi hierarchy json, but my json have all types of values, that includes **urls with black slash, values with special characters, cert keys with new line carriage return** etc.  The assumption is that what ever is in the JSON value should be used to replaced the properties file with it.

Comment: @coolTech Yes? Is your issue the delimiter used in the `sed` substitution?

Comment: Yes, I am getting `sed: file /dev/stdin line 22: unknown option to 's'` error when running the script. I think the section `jq -r ......... | "s/=\\${\(.key)}/=\(.value)/"'` is not able to substitute the values.

Comment: @coolTech Did you see that I changed that to `"s,=\\${\(.key)},=\"\(.value)\","`?

Comment: Thanks, that updated command worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are more appropriate tools to deal with JSON files out there. For this simple case, `awk` may suffice:

```
awk '
NR == FNR       {gsub (/[ ",]/, _)              # in first file, remove "punctuation" chars
                 T[$1] = $2                     # and save replacement values in T array
                 next                    
                }

                {P = $2                         # create pattern
                 gsub (/[${}]/, _, P)           # with redundant / undesired chars removed
                }

P in T          {sub (P, T[P], $2)              # if pattern shows up, replace it
                }

1

' FS=":" file2 FS="=" file1
DATABASE_NAME ${ABC}
DATABASE_HOST ${HOST_ABC}
```